# Item Counter program that will display the number of names that are stored on a file

Tags: java, file

Can someone help me with this java program that I've been puzzled on for a while. I'll post the question alone with the code but its a Files in java that I've recently started and I'm having trouble adding a loop counter variable to hold and display the number of names stored in the file.

For better understanding here the question I'm working on:

Assume that a file containing a series of names (as strings) is named names.dat and exists on the computers disk. Design a program that displays the number of names that are stored in the file. (Hint: Open the file and read every string stored in it. Each time you read a string, increment a counter variable. When you've read all the strings from the file, the counter variable will contain the number of names stored in the file.)

I don't know how much trouble it will be to aid assist being that this question is file related in java.

Here is my java code so far for better understanding:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Item_Counter {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        int numLines = 0;
        int sum = 0;

        File namesFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Tyrese\\JAVA 2\\Chapter 10\\names.dat");
        Scanner bot = new Scanner(namesFile);

        System.out.println(bot.nextLine());

        while (bot.hasNext()) {
            numLines = numLines + 1;
            numLines = bot.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("The file has" + numLines);
    }
}
```

Feel free to replace my file path and name that is a simple notepad document containing a few names, with your own if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You have some errors in your code, the way Scanner works for file reading is simple, you open the file the way you did like this : `Scanner bot = new Scanner(namesFile);` but in order to go to the next line you need to do `bot.nextLine()` so if you do it before you are in the while or do it twice it will go on 2 lines, so you just need to do like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        int numLines = 0; // initialise variable

        File namesFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Tyrese\\JAVA 2\\Chapter 10\\names.dat"); // fetch the file
        Scanner bot = new Scanner(namesFile); // open the file

        while (bot.hasNextLine()) { // while the file has a next line -> go on
            numLines++; // add +1 to the variable numLines
            numLines = bot.nextLine(); // go to the next line (if it has one)
        }
        System.out.println("The file has" + numLines); // print the result
    }
```

You can ask me if you have any further questions

Comment: You can't do ``numLines = bot.nextLine();`` because numLines is an int. Just have `bot.nextLine();`` without the assignment. Otherwise, this is an excellent answer.

Comment: @tyrese you might want to accept this as the correct answer. I have also written an answer which explains the issue in a detailed manner and answers your second question as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problematic part of your code:

```
    System.out.println(bot.nextLine());

    while (bot.hasNext()) {
        numLines = numLines + 1;
        numLines = bot.nextInt();
    }
```

Your `println` types a line being read and therefore that line will be ignored later. You need `hasNextLine` in the while loop and `nextLine` instead of `nextInt`.

Fix:

```
    while (bot.hasNextLine()) {
        numLines = numLines + 1;
        bot.nextLine();
    }
```

You can compute the sum of integers inside a file similarly. However, the actual solution depends on the structure of the file. If the file contains the integers as lines, without white characters beside the newline, such as

```
1
5
4
7
2
7
```

then the solution is:

```
int sum = 0;
while (bot.hasNextLine()) {
    sum += 1;
    bot.nextLine();
}
```

however, if the file is a list of numbers, separated by space, such as

```
3 7 8 2 8 3 6 9
```

then you read the content of the file via

```
String content = bot.nextLine();
String[] splited = str.split("\\s+");
int sum = 0;
for (int index = 0; index < splited.length; index++) {
    sum += Integer.parseInt(splited[index])
}
```

Comment: thanks you @LajosArpad , but do u have a code that explains and calculate the sum of all integer values stored in a file and displays the total?

Comment: @tyrese the answer contains code for that, yes. Displaying it is as simple as `System.out.println(sum);`. In general, on this site we do not tend to ask for code and we do not tend to ask multiple questions in the comment section after the problem has been solved. If you still have questions, you can ask them as separate questions and share a link here.